# For loop index source selector

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, indexing, jquery-selectors

Any ideas why the code returns the `src` when outside the `for` loop, but inside it returns `undefined` for each loop?

```
var deckCount = $(".deck").children().length;
var findCard = $(".deck > .card:eq(1) > img").attr("src");  
console.log("findCard eq1: " , findCard);

for(i=0 ; i < deckCount; i++)
{
    var findCard = $(".deck > .card:eq(i) > img").attr("src");  
    console.log("findCard i: " , findCard);
}
```

View here:
www.jarrettonions.co.za
the code is part of the next button in the image gallery.

Comment: try `.card:eq("+i+")` inside your loop, also it should maybe be `deckCount.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the value of `i` from the variable as follows:

```
var findCard = $(".deck > .card:eq("+i+") > img").attr("src");
```

In your case the `i` is within the selector and it is prohibiting the selection from happening since it is an invalid attribute to the `eq()`

Comment: Thanks! and for the explanation too. I have never seen that method of passing a variable, but the solution works!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `deckCount.length` to get the amount of "elements" in deckCount

Second to use `i` as a value, use `" + i + "`

```
for(i=0 ; i < deckCount.length; i++){

   var findCard = $(".deck > .card:eq(" + i + ") > img").attr("src");  
   console.log("findCard i: " , findCard);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that does it! I have the .lenght part further up in the code but didnt think it was part of the problem

Comment: @JarrettOnions Your very welcome, please remember to mark any of the solutions if either one of them solved your problems

Comment: Yip, it said I could only mark a question as correct in 10min so thats what I came back for now ;)